# Python library to launch browser prompt?

Tags: python

Like it's akin to a CLI prompt

```
if 'y' == input('Do you want to do this? (y/n) '):
```

but I'm looking for something like

```
data = browser_input('fun-data-entry.html')
```

Just like with `input(...)` it would block there and only continue after the form was submitted.

This is for a CLI tool which is used by semi-technical users (they can *sort of* use the command line). There are some rich inputs which would be very painful to input without some familiar GUI (like a browser form).

Any ideas? I could roll my own, open the form in a browser, open a socket to capture the form submit, or spin up a flask server on demand, hang out until form submit, cleanup everything. Just wondering if someone has already figured this out and made it easy to use.

Comment: why not just take the input in the terminal? I dont understand how or why the browser comes into play ... if its really necessary why not just make the whole thing a flask app or something? it seems like this is unnecessarily overcomplicating your program ... but to answer your question there is nothing like that as far as i know

Comment: There are quite a few available GUI options for `python`, not necessarily browser related.  e.g. the built-in `tkinter`, the fancier `pyqt5`, or `kivy` all are available if the solution is not dependent on browser.  For example you could just grab the default message dialog boxes from `tkinter` and get the results.

Comment: yes kivy might be close enough for you it has a .kv file concept that lets you create gui's and interactions with a markdown type language

Comment: These particular users have learned some basic CLI use, but it would not be worth their time to learn to use a terminal text editor or pass lots of args or go through a CLI "wizard", or edit a file on the side and pass a path to it, etc... I can give them guardrails pretty easily with an html form with action="localhost:1234". One of the utilities would be to hand edit some json starting from a template (they can do this much).

Comment: The non-browser dialogue boxes might be good enough for some cases. I'll look into that.